# IllegalAccessError when calling delete() in ContentResolver

Tags: android

Good day to everyone. I can't solve one problem. Any help would be strongly appreciated. 
Exception raised after calling `mContentResolver.delete(CONTENT_URI, TOKEN + "=?) AND (" + OBJECT_ID + "=?", token_obj);` Any suggestions ? Thank you =)

```
private void submitAll() {

    String token = AccountInfoHolder.getInstance().getToken();
    String objectid = AccountInfoHolder.getInstance().getObjectId();

    String[] token_obj = new String[] { token, objectid };

    ContentResolver mContentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    mContentResolver.delete(CONTENT_URI, TOKEN + "=?) AND (" + OBJECT_ID
            + "=?", token_obj);

    submitAttachmentsFromHolder(mPhotoHolder, IMAGE);
    submitAttachmentsFromHolder(mVideoHolder, VIDEO);
    sendEvent(OPEN_UPLOAD_ATTACHMENTS, new UploadAttachmentsArgs(
            REGISTRATION).getData());
}


05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class me.thisnow.database.model.AttachmentContract from class me.thisnow.fragment.ChooseAttachments
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at me.thisnow.fragment.ChooseAttachments.submitAll(ChooseAttachments.java:185)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at me.thisnow.fragment.ChooseAttachments.checkThenSubmit(ChooseAttachments.java:164)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at me.thisnow.fragment.ChooseAttachments.onClick(ChooseAttachments.java:142)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18190)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-13 16:42:40.462: E/AndroidRuntime(14863):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is line 185 of ChooseAttachments.java?

Comment: Also where do you declare `CONTENT_URI`, `TOKEN`, and `OBJECT_ID`?